# How to generate a list from start and step

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list which contains one or two elements, and I want to increment the first element and put it in the next index. The list must contain 3 elements.

```
first case:
intilal list -> [2020]
desired list -> [2020, 2021, 2022]

seconde case:
intilal list -> [2020, 2021]
desired list -> [2020, 2021, 2022]

third case:
intilal list -> [2020, 2021, 2022]
desired list -> do noting
```

Comment: You didn't increment the *first* element in the second example, you incremented the *last*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you want to do if the list is already four elements long?

```
def inc3(alist):
     while len(alist) < 3:
             alist.append(alist[-1]+1)
     return alist
```